# Как проверить, входят ли все элементы одного словаря в другой?

Tags: java

Как можно проверить, содержит ли словарь `map1` все пары `<Key, Value>`, содержащиеся в `map2`?

Comment: Пробежаться по одной мапе и проверить, что такие ключи есть в другой и этим ключам соответствуют те же значения, да и всё.

Comment: **"Все те данные"** -- вы имеете в виду, что все ключи из map1 должны содержаться в map2, или map2 должен содержать такие же ключи с такими же значениями?

Comment: @AlexChermenin а метода какого нить нету, который делал бы такое?

Comment: @m.vokhm такие же ключи с такими же значениями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от того, нужно ли вам проверять только наличие в `map1` всех ключей из `map2`, или еще и равенство соответствующих значений, можете использовать один из двух методов:

```
static boolean containsAllEntries(Map<?,?> map1, Map<?,?> map2) {
    return map1.entrySet().containsAll(map2.entrySet());
}  

static boolean containsAllKeys(Map<?,?> map1, Map<?,?> map2) {
    return map1.keySet().containsAll(map2.keySet());
}  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> 
        map1 = new HashMap<>(), map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map1.put("1", "Один");  map2.put("1", "Один");
    map1.put("2", "Два");       map2.put("2", "Два");
    map1.put("3", "Три");       map1.put("3", "Три");

    map1.put("4", "Четыре");
    map1.put("5", "Пять");

    System.out.println("map1 contains all keys    from map2: " + containsAllKeys(map1, map2));
    System.out.println("map1 contains all entries from map2: " + containsAllEntries(map1, map2));

    map1.put("2", "Не два!");
    System.out.println("map1 contains all keys    from map2: " + containsAllKeys(map1, map2));
    System.out.println("map1 contains all entries from map2: " + containsAllEntries(map1, map2));

    map1.remove("2");
    System.out.println("map1 contains all keys    from map2: " + containsAllKeys(map1, map2));
    System.out.println("map1 contains all entries from map2: " + containsAllEntries(map1, map2));
}
```